# How to implement automatic synchronization in Android?

Tags: android

My application can now synchronize some data to a remote server, and at the moment, it happens  explicitly when my user clicks a button, the app shows a `ProgressDialog` and does the network operation in background with `ASyncTask`.

Now my client requires that the synchronization should happen on any data change. I cannot do it on the "foreground" like it's now, because it usually takes 5-10 seconds on mobile data connection, the app has to collect data from sqlite database, serialize it to JSON and send to remote web service.

Do I have to implement a `Service` that will receive a message from the application that it's time to do the synchronization? Or could I just move my `ASyncTask` to `Application` class and do the operation from there?

Comment: Just a suggestion. There must be some way to find that data has changed on server or not (some time stamp appended to data set). Do that in a service. Upon true(you need new data) use your previous implementation using service is a among best practices. Cheers!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A service would be the best way to do this.